# connections on the universal bundle

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

Two bundle morphisms of a smooth vector bundle into the universal bundle pull the universal connection back to two connections on the veector bundle.

One can also obtain two connections on the bundle from two connections on the universal bundle and a single morphism.

Why doesn't the second method give all of the connections on the vector bundle?

Comment: Why do you think the second method *should* give all the connections?

Comment: Take one of the connections to be trivial and classified by the constant map, but the other nontrivial.

Comment: Have you checked the paper of Narasimhan, Rammanan: http://www.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?arg3=&co4=AND&co5=AND&co6=AND&co7=AND&dr=all&pg4=AUCN&pg5=AUCN&pg6=TI&pg7=ALLF&pg8=ET&review_format=html&s4=&s5=&s6=existence%20of%20universal%20connections&s7=&s8=All&vfpref=html&yearRangeFirst=&yearRangeSecond=&yrop=eq&r=1&mx-pid=151923
 